# how to develop the crossbasis using a binary term

Tags: r

The indicator `hw` is used to show if a day is a heat wave day. I intend to study the exposure-lag relationship of heatwave using `dlnm` in R. When I developed the crossbasis and predicted the results, I got an error as following:

> Error in crosspred(hw.basis, model) :
> coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix. See help(crosspred)

My code:

```
hw.knots <- equalknots(hw, fun="ns",df=4)
hw.logknots <- logknots(10,fun="ns",df=4,intercept=TRUE)  
hw.basis <- crossbasis(hw,lag=10, argvar=list(fun="ns",df=4), arglag=list(knots=hw.logknots))
model <- glm(ntr ~ hw.basis+ dow + ns(time,df=7*7),
         family=quasipoisson(), data)
hw.pred<-crosspred(hw.basis,model)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would be better if you included some sample data that reproduces your error (in the body of your question). That way community members can work with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to upload the sample data. My data is a time series data, including daily death number, day of week, time and hw. hw is valued 1 when it is a heatwave day and 0 when it's not. The maximum lag day is set to 10.

Comment: You might wrap your data object ```hw``` in ```dput()```. Running this code would generate the ```hw``` object in the R console. Then you could copy-paste it to your post using the 'edit' button.